# How to Configure Subdomains to Work For Java Servlets?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets, server.xml

Not managed to find an answer to this anywhere yet, I'm getting close to having this implemented, just one final hurdle that I've not managed to crack.

Single server. Split up using WHM into individual cPanel accounts. 1 instance of Tomcat 7 running. Servlet class files and JSP files deployed.

www.first-website.com - All works perfectly.

www.second-website.com - www. points to another server completely (non-Apache Tomcat / Java), so please ignore that part

sub-domain.second-website.com - Manages to load main Welcome File correctly which is being processed as a Servlet. I'm getting a 404 error though when I try and access sub-domain.second-website.com/about-us/ for example, for all of the sub-directory pages (i.e. url-patterns from web.xml) - this all works on my local machine, so this is something that I've missed configuring the server. The 404 page that it is showing is a server level 404 page, not an Apache Tomcat 404 page which leads me to believe this is an issue somehow related to all of this, http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html - which I'm struggling to understand what this page is actually talking about.

Pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to the specific problem above, add the following to your .htaccess file within your document root for the sub-domain;

```
RewriteEngine on

SetHandler jakarta-servlet

SetEnv JK_WORKER_NAME ajp13
```

Long answer, this is how to do it all, https://www.contradodigital.com/2017/05/24/how-to-install-servlet-support-on-a-subdomain-on-apache-tomcat-7-using-command-line-cpanel-and-whm/